# permanent routes with netplan - ubuntu19.04

Tags: 19.04, netplan

How can I configure my permanent route table on **ubuntu19.04** with **netplan** (/etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist).

Thank you

Comment: Is this a Desktop or Server installation?

Comment: Hello, it's ubuntu 19.04 - Disco in core version.

Comment: I assume that your answer is that this is a Server installation. Have you looked at https://netplan.io/examples